# Searching a variable name or code snippet in all vscode files

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Is there a way in vscode to find files that use with a particular variable name ?  for ex: say all python files that use a variable named source_string .  Not sure if this could be a simple vscode setting or maybe a python code itself. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there something similar for the Jupyter Notebook ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the search function of VS Code found on the left/right side of your window. It has the magnifying glass icon.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click the magnifying glass on the upper left or press Control + Shift + F all at the same time. Then enter your search term and it will list all matches throughout the solution.